# How to adjust the save window?

Tags: window

I have reinstalled Ubuntu recently.After re-installation, the save or browse window which opens up for saving document has expanding view which is out of screen. I am not able to edit the file name while saving. If I start typing it goes to find option.
I have tried resizing the window but that is not responding after it did for the first time and came back to the same when I tried to save the second document. I do not see any types of setting for this particular issue in settings app.
Ubuntu version I am using is 20.04.This happens with all the apps for saving as well as browsing window.